# MySql Shutdowns Every 2-3 Minutes

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, restart

Mysql Shuts down 2-3 minute. I just have a low traffic Drupal instant with all optimization like Boost module etc in place.

I have the following in my log:

```
> 130927 14:55:33 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
> 
> 130927 14:55:52 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. 130927 14:55:52
> InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled 130927 14:55:52 InnoDB:
> Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 130927 14:55:52 InnoDB:
> Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4 130927 14:55:52 InnoDB:
> Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M 130927 14:55:52 InnoDB:
> Completed initialization of buffer pool 130927 14:55:52 InnoDB:
> highest supported file format is Barracuda. InnoDB: Log scan
> progressed past the checkpoint lsn 142353991 130927 14:55:52  InnoDB:
> Database was not shut down normally! InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
> InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files... InnoDB:
> Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
> InnoDB: buffer... InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence
> number 142501965 130927 14:55:53  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of
> log records to the database... InnoDB: Progress in percents: 21 22 23
> 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
> 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69
> 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92
> 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 InnoDB: Apply batch completed 130927 14:55:53 
> InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start 130927 14:55:54
> InnoDB: 5.5.32 started; log sequence number 142501965 130927 14:55:54
> [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306 130927
> 14:55:54 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1'; 130927
> 14:55:54 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'. 130927
> 14:55:54 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events 130927 14:55:54
> [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

I'm not sure whats wrong.

Comment: Are you running the latest version of MySQL? Have you patched your operating system? This is not a programming problem, though. Please see the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The version is 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.  It is standard ubuntu that comes with Amazon EC2. How can I move this question to DBA site ? Can it be done by me or only by Moderators ?

Comment: I've flagged it for moving, but it'll take some more votes to push it over. You can always ask there pre-emptively to see if you get a better response.

Comment: Okay thank you. But asking the same question(cross post) on DBA would violate the rule. So I should better wait.

Comment: Which type of Ec2 Instance you are using? Can you verify the memory utilization of your instance? Just give some brief explanation to resolve the issue.

Comment: This is Ec2 Micro instance. The site doesn't have much traffic. So memory utilization of apache2 and mysqld is not going beyond 20% at anytime(according to top command).